# width=device-width and upper bound on original size

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

As I am developing an mobile app, I set "width=device-width". However, this would lead be image be magnified to fill the screen when viewing in a normal computer. Of course it should be what it is supposed to do, but would it be possible to make it so that the image would at most appear as big as its original size and no more?

Answer (score 1):

Use css:

```
max-width: "somethingpx";
```